# Trigger event on cursor position

Tags: html, css, cursor

Is it possible to trigger an event on a cursor position?

More specifically when the user is moving the cursor to the top of the page, as if they are closing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event handler to the document for onMouseMove that will track every time the mouse changes position.  The event gives you the x and y coordinates.  You cannot track anything outside of the document itself though (like the toolbar or other browser chrome) and you cannot cancel mouse move events as they are read-only